# QGIS plugins not installing

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, plugins

I'm trying to install plugins on a fresh install of QGIS 2.18.12. I can connect to the plugins repository but trying to install any plugin fails with the error message:

> Failed to unzip plugin package. Probably it is broken or missing from
> the repository. You may also want to make sure that you have the right
> permissions to the plugin directory

I've tried rebooting and checked permissions on the repository folder. I've also tried setting an http proxy in the network settings.

None of the above has worked.

Comment: Perhaps try downloading the [zipped file](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/) and extract it to your /.qgis2/python/plugins/ directory manually. Restart QGIS and see if that helps